# how to change the image style received from webservice in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone

[image]

I am sharing the screen shot of my application. The image which is coming i want it to be in the side and should be small in size. Here i am not getting the full image also. Can anyone help me to fit the image in the listbox and appear it in the side.

My xaml code is:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
     <ListBox Name="listBox1">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button>
                        <Button.Content>
                            <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="80" Width="400">
                                <!--<ScrollViewer Height="80">-->
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="80">

                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=News_Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" ></TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=News_Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
                                      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Date_Start}" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
                                        <Image Source="{Binding ImageBind }" />

                                    </StackPanel>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Button.Content>
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

    </Grid>
```

My .cs code is:

```
public class Newss
{
    public string News_Title { get; set; }
    public string News_Description { get; set; }
    public string Date_Start { get; set; }
    public string image_path { get; set; }
    public BitmapImage ImageBind{get;set;}

}

public News()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    KejriwalService.aapSoapClient client = new KejriwalService.aapSoapClient();
    client.getarvindNewsCompleted += new EventHandler<KejriwalService.getarvindNewsCompletedEventArgs>(client_getarvindNewsCompleted);
    client.getarvindNewsAsync();
}

void client_getarvindNewsCompleted(object sender, KejriwalService.getarvindNewsCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    string result = e.Result.ToString();
    List<Newss> listData = new List<Newss>();
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(result);

   foreach (var location in doc.Descendants("UserDetails"))
   {
        Newss data = new Newss();


        data.News_Title = location.Element("News_Title").Value;

        //data.News_Description = location.Element("News_Description").Value;
        data.Date_Start = location.Element("Date_Start").Value;
        data.image_path = location.Element("image_path").Value;
        data.ImageBind = new BitmapImage(new Uri( @"http://political-leader.vzons.com/ArvindKejriwal/images/uploaded/"+data.image_path, UriKind.Absolute));

        listData.Add(data);
    }

    listBox1.ItemsSource = listData;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move your `Image` outside inner `StackPanel` :

```
.....
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,0">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="80">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=News_Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" ></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=News_Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Date_Start}" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
    <Image Source="{Binding ImageBind }" />
</StackPanel>
.....
```

That will make the `Image` appear besides the Text. Then try to set `Width` and `Height` properties of `Image` control to fixed value, and set `Stretch` property appropriately. See this [post](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Using-the-Image-control-in-Silverlight-2-Beta-1.aspx) for reference about setting `Stretch` property.

Answer (score 1):

There're too many wrong things here, and I don't know what you want.

1. You've put buttons inside items of ListBox. You should either remove buttons and rely on listbox own items selection mechanism for handling touch elents, or continue using buttons but replace ListBox with ItemsControl that doesn’t handle touch.
2. You’ve put ScrollViewer inside those buttons. So if you have 10 items, you’ll have 10 buttons, each with its own scroll viewer. Why you did that?
3. You’ve set height of your StackPanel to 80. When specifying fixed height, Silverlight often does not care whether the content fits or no, instead it clips things. It’s rarely a good idea to specify absolute size of elements.
4. Instead of using two nested stack panels, you should use single Grid with two rows and two columns, where image occupies both rows of the second column (using Grid.RowSpan property).

And you’re asking question about changing image style? You should fix the rest of your XAML first…

Comment: Fix what I told you, esp. my item #4, then set Stretch=Uniform attribute of the image. With your 2 stack panels instead of the grid it won’t help.